# Get String value if present or null if not present using Java8 Stream

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, filtering

I have a json similar like as shown below. The requirement is to get the key value based on the id. ie. lets say If Id is  **A1** key value should return **2gAwIBAgIQKGZsKfAUzaJHVantyrwVdzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQs**. The key array will always conatins only one element.

```
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "id": "A1",
      "key": [
        "2gAwIBAgIQKGZsKfAUzaJHVantyrwVdzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQs"
      ]
    },
     {
      "id": "A2",
      "key": [
        "swKQYDVQQDEyJhY2NvdW50cy5hY2Nlc3Njb250cm9sfsf2dew"
      ]
    },
     {
      "id": "A3",
      "key": [
        "EyJhY2NvdW50cy5hY2Nlc3Njb250cm9sLndpbmRvd3Mubdwe2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

To implement the above I have wrote the below code using Java8 Stream but the problem is that it returns `Optional<KeyDetails>` which again I needs to parse and get the key value

```
String keyDetails = "{\"keys\":[{\"id\":\"A1\",\"key\":[\"2gAwIBAgIQKGZsKfAUzaJHVantyrwVdzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQs\"]},{\"id\":\"A2\",\"key\":[\"swKQYDVQQDEyJhY2NvdW50cy5hY2Nlc3Njb250cm9sfsf2dew\"]},{\"id\":\"A3\",\"key\":[\"EyJhY2NvdW50cy5hY2Nlc3Njb250cm9sLndpbmRvd3Mubdwe2\"]}]}";
AccessKeys accessKeys = new ObjectMapper().readValue(keyDetails, AccessKeys.class);
Optional<KeyDetails> filteredKey = accessKeys.getKeys().stream().filter(key-> key.getId().equals("A3")).findAny();
if(filteredKey.isPresent()) {
    String keyValue = filteredKey.get().getKey().get(0);
    System.out.println("keyValue==>"+keyValue);
}
```

What I want is to get `Optional<String>` instead of `Optional<KeyDetails>`. i.e if the id is present it should return just the key value which is present within the key array.

Some condition that the json satisfies were:

- Sometimes there can be a situation for duplicate key id, in that case it should pick only one (first one)
- Key array will always contains one string value

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: try this `accessKeys.getKeys()
     .stream().filter(key-> key.getId(.equals("A3")).findAny()
     .map(filteredKey->filteredKey.getKey().get(0))
     .orElse(null);`

Comment: your code seems according to your requirements apart from the fact that you should use `findFirst` instead of `findAny` to guarantee that the first item is returned. what's the problem you're having? what's the question here?

Comment: @HadiJ Thanks for that answer, but how to get `Optional<String>` instead of plain `String`

Comment: @Aomine Actually I want to avoid `filteredKey.get().getKey().get(0);` within my `if(filteredKey.isPresent())`  code

Comment: @HadiJ Also as per @Aomine suggest can we use `findFirst` instead of `findAny` since there can be multiple duplicate ids

Comment: @AlexMan you misunderstood me. Hadi's previous comment was correct **but** only if you don't care about which matched item is returned i.e. the behaviour of `findAny` is documented to be explicitly nondeterministic; it is free to select any element in the stream. This is even truer in the case of a parallel stream, but in a sequential stream both `findFirst` and `findAny` should behave the same but since you want the "first" match to be returned it would be wise to explicitly state that via `firstFirst` so in case you want to go parallel the expected result wouldn't change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Sometimes there can be a situation for duplicate key id, in that case
>   it should pick only one (first one)

You're looking for the `map` method (to transform) and `findFirst` instead of `findAny` to always guarantee the first match is returned.

```
accessKeys.getKeys()
          .stream()
          .filter(key-> key.getId().equals("A3"))
          .findFirst()
          .map(e -> e.getKey().get(0)).orElse(null);
```

`findAny`, as the name suggests, should be used in cases where you don't care which matched item is returned. Yes, both `findFirst` and `findAny` will act the same in a sequential stream but I'd rather make my intention clear in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how to get `Optional<String>` instead of plain `String` as return

Comment: @AlexMan remove the `.orElse(null)`